# Set global maxRequestLength value in web.config- for all pages

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config

I currently have my web.config location section set up like this

```
<location path="page1.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" executionTimeout="3600"/>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="page2.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" executionTimeout="3600"/>
  </system.web>
</location>

 etc
```

with one entry for each page.

How can I set the maxRequestLength for all pages, instead of one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly add under `Configuration section` , this will be set for all pages.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" executionTimeout="3600"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in your base/parent `<system.web>` section.